# why is the location string not showing in the window. tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to write a code that will tell you if the location is a file or directory. if its a file, then it will read the file. here is my code (ik its very bad, im sorry)

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.title("files and directories")
screen.geometry("300x100")

def FileDir():
    path = location.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    location.delete(1.0, tk.END)

    if os.path.exists(path):
        print("✔ - this location exists")

        info_location = tk.Label(screen, text=f"location: {location}")
        info_location.pack()

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print("\tthis is a file")
            type = 'file'

            info_type = tk.Label(screen, text=f"type: {type}")
            info_type.pack()

            while True:
                open_file = input("\nDo you want to read this file? ")

                if open_file.lower() == 'yes':
                    with open(path) as file:
                        contents = file.read()
                    print(contents)
                    break

                elif open_file.lower() == 'no':
                    print("goodbye!")
                    break

                else:
                    print("invalid input")
                    continue

        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            print("\tthis is a directory")
            type = 'directory'

            info_type = tk.Label(screen, text=f"type: {type}")
            info_type.pack()

    else:
        print("✘ - this location doesn't exist")

text = tk.Label(screen, text="Enter file/directory location: ")
text.pack()

location = tk.Text(screen, height = 1, width = 25)
location.pack()

enter_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Enter", command=FileDir)
enter_btn.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

so when putting the location of a string, everything works fine except that the location doesnt show and instead it shows ".!text". anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location` is a widget rather than a string. The string representation of a tkinter widget is its internal name. Thus, when you do `text=f"location: {location}"` you are creating a string that contains the name of the widget rather than the contents.

To display the contents you must fetch them from the widget.  You're already doing that when you define `path`, so you just need to use `{path}` rather than `{location}`

```
text=f"location: {path}"
```